# Таймер обратного отcчета

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Делаю таймер обратного отсчета, таймер должен запускаться 1-го числа месяца, отсчет на 3 дня. По истечению 3 дней — запускаться снова. Каждого 1-го числа нового месяца должен сбрасываться.

```js
(function timer() {
  var today = new Date();
  var start = new Date(2016, 3, 1);
  var end = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), start.getDate() + 3);

  
  if ( today.getDate() == end.getDate() || today.getDate() == 1 ) {
    end.setDate( today.getDate() + 3 );
    end.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  
  var differenceTime, dd, hh, mm, ss, str;

  differenceTime = end - new Date();

  dd = parseInt( differenceTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) );
  hh = parseInt( differenceTime / (60 * 60 * 1000) ) % 24;
  mm = parseInt( differenceTime / (1000 * 60) ) % 60;
  ss = parseInt( differenceTime / 1000 ) % 60;
  
  console.log(dd, hh, mm, ss);
  
  setTimeout(timer, 1000);
})();
```

Вот что у меня получилось. Но я не уверен, правильно ли я сделал. Прошу указать на ошибки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. ошибка: прописанный прямо в коде текущий месяц. В мае этот код будет уже нерабочим. Надо брать текущую дату и выяснять, какой сейчас месяц.
2. очередной конец периода: что наступит раньше – 1-е число следующего месяца, или следующее число этого месяца, кратное 3 + 1. Не прозевайте смену года.
3. наконец, если хотите секундный обратный отсчёт, учтите, что таймер JS очень неточный: с `setTimeout( ..., 1000)` некоторые секунды могут пропускаться. Поэтому лучше ставить меньшее значение, и обновлять отображение оставшегося времени чаще.

```js
(function(){
  var timer = function() {
    var today = new Date(), end = new Date(), dd, hh, mm, ss;

    end.setDate( 1 + Math.ceil(end.getDate()/3) * 3); // 1,4,7,..
    if( end.getMonth() !== today.getMonth()) end.setDate(1);
    end.setHours(0);
    end.setMinutes(0);
    end.setSeconds(0);

    ss = Math.round((end.getTime() - today.getTime())/1000); // осталось, в секундах
    dd = Math.floor( ss / 86400); // суток
    ss -= dd * 86400;
    hh = Math.floor( ss / 3600);  // часов
    ss -= hh * 3600;
    mm = Math.floor( ss / 60);    // минут
    ss -= mm * 60;

    document.body.innerText = 'До ' + end.toString() +' '+ dd+' д. и ' + [ pad(hh), pad(mm), pad(ss)].join(':');
  };
  
  var pad = function(i) {
    return ('0' + i).slice(-2);
  };
  
  window.setInterval(timer, 200);
})();
```

Тут есть одна ошибка: если уже начался день, когда сбрасывается таймер, конец неверно посчитается в прошлом: начало этого же дня. Подумайте, как это исправить.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ. Не могли бы вы поправить мой код? Я просто не совсем понял.

Comment: Просто взять и сделать за вас работу/учебное задание? Нет. Что именно вы не совсем поняли? – давайте, я объясню подробнее.

Comment: Вы написали, что нужно брать текущую дату и выяснять, какой сейчас месяц. В моем коде:  `var end = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), start.getDate() + 3);` — берется текущая дата, просто когда 3 дня истекут прибавляются еще 3 дня. И для чего выяснять текущий месяц?

Comment: До меня кажется дошло. Взгляните, пожалуйста: http://jsbin.com/negerupufo/edit?js,output

Comment: Месяц нужен, чтобы в феврале не получить 31-е число. Выражения `start = new Date(2016, 3, 1);` и `start.getDate() + 3` не имеют много смысла, т.к. `start.getDate()` это просто число 1 – можно просто держать переменную с целым значением.